# How to extract only the rows using where clause and Like operator in SQL

Tags: sql, where-clause, sql-like

I have a column with data 0xxxx and 00xxx. How to extract only the rows of 0xxxx with second digit not being '0' using where clause and Like operator in SQL

Comment: Which DBMS do you use?

Comment: You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful, too.

Answer (score 2):

You can use SQL `wild cards` to achieve your result.

```
SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE yourColumn LIKE '0[!0]%';
```

Above, will fetch you results which starts with `0` but not followed by `0`

You can get more information about the `wild cards` from [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Substring might do this for you :

```
Select * from Table where SUBSTRING(column1, 2, 1) <> '0'
```

Answer (score 0):

For standard SQL syntax do

```
SELECT * from tableName
WHERE columnName NOT LIKE '00%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
select * from table
    where column_text
    not like '00%'
```